# Not able to load 'shiny' package

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am not able to load shiny package.I installed shiny successfully but while loading the library I am getting the error below.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘shiny’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    there is no package called ‘htmltools’

Comment: your message suggests `install.packages("htmltools")`..

Comment: Thanks!.But I tried that before.But I am getting this error.

Comment: trying URL 'http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/htmltools_0.3.6.zip'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/htmltools_0.3.6.zip'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  cannot open URL http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/htmltools_0.3.6.zip': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available, : download of package ‘htmltools’ failed

Comment: can you download from this link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmltools/index.html. Then install it manually

Comment: Also try ```install.packages("shiny", dependencies=TRUE)```

Comment: Thanks!.But both the options are not working.I think the problem is with the firewall/security of my office computer